# Why EF keep refusing "Include" on extended primary key in IdentityUserRole?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I extended my `IdentityUser` and `IdentityUserToken`. I am trying to output users and their roles. I keep getting this error

> InvalidOperationException: The property 'RoleId' is not a navigation
>   property of entity type 'IdentityUserRole'. The
>   'Include(string)' method can only be used with a '.' separated list of
>   navigation property names.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsersList()
    {
      var users = await context.UserRoles
                        .Include(x=>x.RoleId)
                        .ToListAsync();

        return Ok(users);

    }
```

so I tried to add in my DbContext did not work either,

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

         modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasKey(hk => new { hk.UserId, hk.RoleId});
          base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

why `UserId` or `RoleId` are not navigation properties, how can I use `Include` in this case?

Comment: You don't need to use `Include` for non-navigation properties ... what problem are you trying to solve here? Nominally you'd do something like `context.Users.Include(u => u.Roles)`

Comment: this table is shared between users and roles, calling it and including these keys will automatically include the data from the other tables, no?

Comment: `context.Users.Include(u => u.Roles)` does not work, Roles has no definition in my Identity table, they are linked via `UserId` and `RoleId`

Comment: If there are no navigation properties between the entities you can still use [`join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause) or [`Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534644(v=vs.110).aspx)/[`GroupJoin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534805(v=vs.110).aspx) and do it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case someone struggles with extended Identity I am posting the answer down here, and the ref is [here](https://forums.asp.net/p/2134003/6184575.aspx?p=True&t=636504117862486795).

1.Modify the ApplicationUser to add Roles Property

```
// Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Navigation property for the roles this user belongs to.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole<string>> Roles { get; } = new List<IdentityUserRole<string>>();

    // your rest properties
}
```

2. Modify ApplicationDbContext to add Role to User Entity

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Roles)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
                .IsRequired()
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

3. Build Project-> Package Manager Console-> Run add-migration addroletouser->Update-database

4. Get Users with roles by code below:

   `var users = await _context.ApplicationUser.Include(u => u.Roles).ToListAsync();`